# Double conditional - delete all folders older than 3 days but keep a minimum of 10

Tags: ansible

I have a bit of problem I can't seem overcome. I have a folder with a lot of folders that are generated. I want to delete all folders that are older than three days, but I want to keep a minimum of 10 folders.

I came up with this half-working code and I'd like some suggestions how to tackle this.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    # find all files that are older than three
    - find:
        paths: "/Users/asteen/Downloads/sites/"
        age: "3d"
        file_type: directory
      register: dirsOlderThan3d

    # find all files that are in the directory
    - find:
        paths: "/Users/asteen/Downloads/sites/"
        file_type: directory
      register: allDirs

    # delete all files that are older than three days, but keep a minimum of 10 files
    - file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}" 
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ dirsOlderThan3d.files }}"
      when: allDirs.files > 10 and not item[0].exists ... item[9].exists
```

Comment: Find all folders that are three days old or newer; if they are 10 or more, delete the rest; otherwise find the 10 more recent and delete the rest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to filter your list of files older than 3 days:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: find all files that are older than three
      find:
        paths: "/Users/asteen/Downloads/sites/"
        age: "3d"
        file_type: directory
      register: dirsOlderThan3d
    - name: remove older than 3 days but first ten newest
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}" 
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ (dirsOlderThan3d.files | sort(attribute='ctime'))[:-10] | list }}"
```

Comment: It should be `sort(attribute='ctime', reverse=true)` - otherwise it keeps ten oldest and removes newer ones. Also, this keeps 10 folders older than 3 days even if there are 10+ folders newer than 3 days.

Comment: Right for the order, I changed for `[:-10]` instead to remove the last 10 (the 10 newest) from the list of folders to delete.
About the other point, from what I understand from the question, all files newer than 3 days must be kept and for the older than 3 days, keep only the 10 newest.

Answer (score 0):

I've been previously using a **cronjob** with **find** and decided to move to AWX and after checking here and other articles, I've come up with the following. Tested and working as we speak. First task registers all files older than 3 days as being **matched_files_dirs**. Second task removes them. Does the job but is slower than just running **cron** on linux:

```
find /opt/system*/target_directories -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;



---
- name: Cleanup
  hosts: linux
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Collect files
    shell: find /opt/system*/target_directories -type f -mtime +3
    register: matched_files_dirs
    
  - name: Remove files
    become_user: root
    file: 
        path: "{{ item }}" 
        state: absent
    with_items: "{{ matched_files_dirs.stdout_lines }}"
```